# Click on month in Silverlight Calendar in year mode, get the selected month and stay in year mode?

Tags: silverlight, calendar

I want to provide a user the ability to select a month\year  I was going to just use 2 listboxes but I say that the Silverlight calendar had a year mode, which displays the months of a year (not the months with all the days).

But when you click on a month it switches to displaying the days in the month selected (month mode).

I tried switching back to the year mode in the SelectedDatesChanged event.  But realized that fires only after I select a specific day in a month (at which point it does switch back the the year mode).

So my questions:
- can I get the calendar to stay in the year mode?
- is there an event for the month selected?
- can I even get the month select?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a DisplayModeChanged event that can be used.  I my case I needed the first date and the last date of the selected month ... the code below does what I needed.

```
private void CalendarDisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    //control might be null at start up so check for null
    //probably could hook up event in Loaded or constructor instead of xaml to prevent this
    if (calendarInYearMode != null) {
          //reset back to year mode
        calendarInYearMode.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
        if (calendarInYearMode.DisplayDate != DateTime.MinValue) {
            var beginningOfMonthDate = calendarInYearMode.DisplayDate;
            var endOfMonthDate = calendarInYearMode.DisplayDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);       
        }
    }
}
```